# Adding same filter twice on Presto?

Tags: sql, performance, hive, presto

I am currently working with Presto and trying to automate queries as much as possible. The tables that I worked with are some partitioned daily, and some monthly. To make the query building more comfortable, I ended up doing two functions:

- `add_partitions`: A function that takes a [Query Object](https://pypika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/2_tutorial.html) and adds the filters that correspond to the partitions of the table defined.
- `add_date_filters`: A function that takes a [Query Object](https://pypika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/2_tutorial.html) and adds filters for the dates.

This can be used together, resulting in adding the same filter twice (For example, the daily partitioned tables will have the `day` field filter added twice, once because it is a partition and once because it is a date field).

The question is, does this have an impact on the performance in any way? I've checked and it works, but I'm not sure if it may add extra unnecessary workload. Also, how does this change if the defined filter is on a partition o not? (I imagine that if the filter is a partition it won't change much, even in the worst case scenario of Presto not recognizing the repeated filter).

Comment: If the conditions are connected by `AND`, there should not be a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, glad that it doesn't change performance. Would you mind explaining a bit more how it doesn't? Maybe put it as answer for me to be able to approve it.

Comment: Usually, evaluating filter conditions is not a significant cost. Reading the data and joins, aggregations are usually much more important from performance perspective. Of course, this is unless your filter condition are unusually complex or involve bigger than usual values (eg maps or arrays with many entries).

Comment: @FelipeGonzalez . . . I'm not 100% sure, so you should test.  However, any reasonable implementation is going to look at the `WHERE` clause, see it is connected by `AND`s and pull out any conditions that relate to partitioning.  Anything more refined, such as determining inter-relationships would just complicate that logic.  So, I'm pretty sure that the partitions will be picked up as you want.  But, it is always worth testing.